# Cannot find Natural front 3D facial animation plugin in Window drop down

Tags: unity

I am using Unity version 5.4.2 which is the latest, I tried to go through the tutorial video for creating 3D animations of 2D pictures but I am unable to find the icon of

-> Natural front 3D facial animation plugin

under the window drop down. What is the step I am missing? Am i supposed to download anything extra?

Answer (score 0):

The Natural Front 3D animation plugin is not included by default with unity. If you do a quick search on the unity store you should be able to find [A](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/64351) [Few](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/56653) [Varieties.](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/64600)

Generally if it has plugin in the name that alludes to an extra install.